# Why can this differential equation be written in $3$ different ways?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose we have the following differential equation using operator notation: $$(D-x)(D+x)y=0\tag{1}$$ where $$D=\frac{d}{dx}$$

Now I could rewrite $(1)$ as $$\begin{align}\require{enclose}(D-x)(D+x)y&=\left(\frac{d}{dx}-x\right)\left(y^{\prime}+xy\right)\\&=y^{\prime\prime}+\bbox[#AFA]{\left(xy\right)^{\prime}}-xy^{\prime}-x^2y\\&=y^{\prime\prime}+\bbox[#AFA]{y+\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{xy^{\prime}}}-\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{xy^{\prime}}-x^2y\\&\implies \fbox{$y^{\prime\prime}-x^2y + y = 0$}\tag{a}\end{align}$$

Or, by switching the order of the brackets; I could rewrite $(1)$ as $$\begin{align}\require{enclose}(D-x)(D\color{blue}{\textbf{ + }}x)y&=(D+x)(D\color{red}{\textbf{ - }}x)y\\&=\left(\frac{d}{dx}+x\right)\left(y^{\prime}-xy\right)\\&=y^{\prime\prime}\bbox[#FAA]{-\left(xy\right)^{\prime}}+xy^{\prime}-x^2y\\&=y^{\prime\prime}\bbox[#FAA]{-y-\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{xy^{\prime}}}+\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{xy^{\prime}}-x^2y\\&\implies \fbox{$y^{\prime\prime}-x^2y - y = 0$}\tag{b}\end{align}$$

Lastly, I could rewrite $(1)$ as $$\begin{align}\require{enclose}(D-x)(D+x)y&=(D^2-x^2)y\\&=\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-x^2\right)y\\&=y^{\prime\prime}-x^2y\\&\implies\ \fbox{$y^{\prime\prime}-x^2y = 0$}\tag{c}\end{align}$$

There's no doubt there's most probably a simple explanation for it; but how can the same differential equation $(1)$ be written in three different ways: $(\mathrm{a})$, $(\mathrm{b})$, $(\mathrm{c})$?

Many thanks.

Comment: Now explain the downvote

Comment: Did not down vote, but the answer is obvious. Operators $D-x$ and $D+x$ do not commute. (You cannot switch the orders)

Comment: @mastrok Thanks for that; it was not obvious to me. Do you have any sources/links that explain/prove _why_ operators are not commutative?

Comment: @BLAZE: look e.g. at the quantum harmonic oscillator. Your observation derives from the elementary fact that $[D,x] =1$ with $[D,x]= Dx -xD$ the commutator. This statement is a statement about operators, thus it means that $[D,x]y =y$ or $(Dx-xD)y=y$.

Comment: You have already shown that $(D-x)(D+x) \neq (D+x)(D-x) \neq D^2 -x^2$.  It means that the first line in your $(b)$ and $(c)$ are not valid.

Comment: @mastrok Okay that's great; would you care to make this as an answer then I can upvote and accept? I hate leaving questions that stay open forever.

Comment: Since you already figured it out, why don't you answer the question yourself? :)

Comment: @mastrok I guess I could do that; but it is disrespectful in my honest opinion, since I would only be copying your explanation (essentially plagiarism). Looks like this one will be left open then (:

Comment: I have answered it as CW, since neither of you two want to! That means no one gets points, but if @BLAZE would accept it, the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D+x$ and $D-x$ do not commute. Your (b) is a demonstration of this.

In (c) you are equating $(D+x)(D-x)$ and $D^2-x^2$, but that is wrong for a similar reason - in $D^2-x^2$ the first $D$ is no longer acting on the second $x$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer; best regards.

Comment: Apart from the not getting any points; What is the difference between Community Wiki answers and those that are not?

Comment: You would have to check the help pages. I think you need less reputation to edit them.

Comment: Okay, thanks; I'll take a look.