# Could someone please verify whether or not this is a book error?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

`Below is a short extract for which I believe there may be an error:`

[image: Short extract]

---

I think that equations $(22.3)$ and $(22.4)$ have been written out wrongly, they should be written as:
$$(D+x)(D-x)y_n=-2ny_n\tag{22.3}$$
$$(D-x)(D+x)y_n=-2(n+1)y_n\tag{22.4}$$

where the signs of have been reversed.

Can anyone please provide confirmation on whether or not this is a book error?

Comment: Unless I'm missing some context here, the order of those two factors won't end up mattering, also, it might be the opposite order you were expecting because of how this author orders composition. (both orders for composition are still used for a variety of reasons despite the potential for confusion).

Comment: @Justin The order of the factors does matter as operators in general do not commute I had this pointed out to me [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837895/why-can-this-differential-equation-be-written-in-3-different-ways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no error here.

$$(D-x)(D+x)y_n = y_n^{''}-x^2y_n + y_n = -(2n+1)y_n + y_n = -2ny_n$$

and

$$(D+x)(D-x)y_n = y_n^{''}-x^2y_n - y_n = -(2n+1)y_n - y_n = -2ny_n-2y_n = -2(n+1)y_n$$

I'm assuming here that you see why the result in $(22.2)\ $ is correct - the operators don't commute. Given that, the results in $(22.3)\ $ and $(22.4)\ $ correctly follow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I do see why the result of $(22.2)$ is correct, I appreciate your time.

Comment: @BLAZE Happy to help, I was in the midst of editing to show the result in 22.2 when you accepted my answer, saving me the trouble. :)

Comment: My post provided a partial result to 22.2, leaving an observation of a complete solution, so there's no need to repeat the answer.

Comment: @StevenHarding I know, but that was the same part covered in the book excerpt. It's the second part of 22.2 I wanted to show for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

$(D - x)(D + x)y = (D - x)(Dy + xy) = (D - x)Dy + (D - x)xy = D^2y - xDy + Dxy - x^2y = D^2y - xDy + (y + xDy) - x^2y = D^2y + y - x^2y$

Then $(D - x)(D + x)y_n = D^2y_n + y_n - x^2y_n = -(2n + 1)y_n + y_n = -2ny_n$

Comment: Thanks for showing that there was no error.